# Can I use Roslyn in .net standard 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

Can I use Roslyn in .Net standard 2.0? Nuget package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp is only for .Net Framework. Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the second point under Details section on [github announcement](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/439). Personally, I already tried referencing v2.3.0 analyzer assemblies in netstandard 2.0 library and it worked (though admittedly I run it on full framework in the end).

Try it and you will see if it works in your case. If not, wait for official support or raise an issue.